# How to get the distance in meter from PointCloud Data?

Tags: ros, sensor, avoid-obstacle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am pretty new with ROS and Robotino. I am using ROS-Indigo, Ubuntu 14.4 and Robotino by Festo. I am subscribing the ros topic /distance_sensor :

```
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/distance_sensors",1, distacne_sensor_Callback); 
void distacne_sensor_Callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloudConstPtr& msg) 
{
       for (i=0;i<msg->points.size();i++) {
        ROS_INFO("X : %f",  msg->points[i].x);
        ROS_INFO("Y : %f",  msg->points[i].y);
        ROS_INFO("Z : %f",  msg->points[i].z);
}
```

I am getting the x,y,z values for each of the 9 distance sensors. How can I get the distance in meter using these data? I need to use these for obstacle detection.
Can anyone give me any idea on this issue?
Thank is advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238728/how-to-get-the-distance-in-meter-from-pointcloud-data?/) by [rasoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26785/rasoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2016-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

points[i] gives you information about the ith point from the frame of the sensor. That is, if

```
points[i] = {
    x : 0.2
    y : 1.2
    z : 0.6
}
```

that means that ith point is at (0.2,1.2,0.6) in the frame of the sensor. Assuming the sensor is fixed to the body of your robot, you can use a static transformation to transform that information to your base_link frame. You can read up on transforms here : http://wiki.ros.org/tf

I hope you are clear. If not, let me know.

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2016-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rasoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26785/rasoo/) on 2016-07-05**:
Thanks for your response. I already go through the link and understand the point and x,y,z coordinate.
But i need to detect obstacle based on distance sensor data. Robotino has 9 sensors in the circle base of the robot. Each of them are 40' angular distance. I need help to calculate the distance.

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2016-07-05**:
I'm not clear on one thing. When you say PointCloud data are published to the topic /distance_sensors, do you mean it actually publishes the locations of the actual distance senors wrt the robot? If that is the case then there should be a different topic that publishes your distance sensor readings

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-19**:
Does the (x,y,z) coordinates from the point cloud give the real world distances? After reading [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/36142/points-in-a-pointcloud-and-their-distance-from-camera/?comment=239611#post-id-239611),my understanding was the coordinates are used to create a projected image.

**Comment by [rasoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26785/rasoo/) on 2016-07-19**:
I also read that earlier.I got the obstacle distance from kinect depth image. Actually Z is not the distance. Z is the distance from the camera to the center point of the image plane. That is why we need to calculate the tangent of the point to get the actual distance.

**Comment by [rasoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26785/rasoo/) on 2016-07-19**:
I actually tried this same approach to find distance from the distance sensors. But I am not sure if it is appropriate for getting distance from distance sensor. It is working for sensor 7 and but for the other sensor it is not working properly. Expecting help from guys who have worked with robotino